# Protecting Sheets stops Macro from working

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I know there are lots of questions on this, which I have read - but none seem to give me the code I need to make this work.

I have a number of buttons that I have placed in the Ribbon of my excel sheet. These are attached to macros that copy sheets onto another sheet, as an example

The macro is ran by pressing the button:

```
Sub btnSheet1_onAction(control As IRibbonControl)

    mFunction.CopySheet1toSheet2

End Sub
```

The macro is contained in my mFunction module as :

```
Public Sub CopySheet1toSheet2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
ws.Cells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells

End Sub
```

Now.... I need to protect items/cells in sheet 1 and 2. When I protect the sheets the macros make excel crash - no runtime errors or anything.

I have inserted the following code into the 'ThisWorkbook'

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets(1).Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets(2).Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

But it still doesn't work - I have also tried with the following code in the mFunction module

```
Public Sub CopySheet1toSheet2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

ws.Unprotect Password = "secret"
ws.Cells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells
ws.Protect Password = "secret"

End Sub
```

But that doesn't seem to work either - I am guessing it might be something to do with the fact that the macro is copying the sheet into another sheet that is locked also?

I should also note that there are other sheets in the workbook that are protected, but that do not have macros attached to them, so they stay protected, could this be causing an issue?

Some help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If a real crash happens *"excel crash - no runtime errors or anything."* then this is in first place not a VBA coding issue but an Excel bug. Make sure you use the latest Excel build version make an update if necessary. The code looks good to me.

Comment: Excel just goes into 'Not Responding' - If I take all the protection off, it works fine. I have the latest version of Excel, and it doesn't just happen on my PC/Excel - anyone that tries to use the spreadsheet experiences the same, so I figure it must be some issue in the code that it is making it do that?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint here `mFunction.CopySheet1toSheet2` and then go through the code step by step using F8 to figure out which line of code causes the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UserInterFaceOnly**

When you save a Workbook with sheets that have been protected using `UserInterFaceOnly`, this property is ***removed*** on the file that is saved. So on reopening the file the sheets will remain protected but can not be changed programmatically either.

So, regarding this piece of code, which on first glance appears to do exactly what you need:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets(1).Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets(2).Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

.. if you save and reopen your file, when your above `Workbook_Open()` runs it will fail to set the protection as there is already protection in place.

The workaround is to include lines for each sheet that remove any protection in place first. Then you can set it again correctly - like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Sheets(1).Unprotect Password:="secret"
    Sheets(2).Unprotect Password:="secret"
    Sheets(1).Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Sheets(2).Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

This should then allow your copy code to run without issue as I can't see much wrong with that part at all.

---

Incidentally, if your passwords are the same, you could tidy it up slightly with:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Array(Sheets(1), Sheets(2))
        sh.Unprotect Password:="secret"
        sh.Protect Password:="secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so I have used this as a work around, but if anyone can give a more eloquent solution that would be great:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

ws1.Unprotect ("2402")
ws2.Unprotect ("2402")
ws1.Cells.Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells
ws1.Protect ("2402")
ws2.Protect ("2402")
```